# How to filter channel by numeric field?

Tags: ee2, templates, channel, filter

If I have a channel with the custom field "Age" (numeric type) how can I filter the channel so that only entries with `"Age" >= 24` are shown?

Likewise what would be the way to define and filter a custom field using a date?

Would this require custom SQL statements or could this be achieved using the `exp:channel:entries` tag?

Comment: Hi Lea, are you using an add on numeric field type or is it actually a text input that you only put numbers into?

Comment: @UltraBob I guess it must be a text input that you can put numbers into. Is there a way to define an actual numeric field type?

Comment: Hi Lea, there may be an add-on fieldtype for it, but I couldn't find one in a quick search.  Using a text input is just fine as long as you input only numbers, I was just curious because a) I hadn't heard of one, b) It would actually be useful to be able to sort by a field numerically in the channel:entries tag.  I may have to look into writing such a fieldtype if it doesn't exist, because it may solve an existing issue I have.

Comment: @UltraBob if you do write one any chance that you could post it to GitHub?

Comment: If I do, you can count on it! ;)

Comment: @UltraBob Out of interest do you have any open source EE bits?

Comment: At the moment, a really simple one that came about due to [this question](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/112/how-can-i-enable-httponly-cookies-in-ee) (linked there).  Most of the add-on development I've done has been for internal use, but I hope to start doing more general stuff going forward, as I get deeper into ee2.

Comment: @UltraBob seems like this plugin is a must, odd how this is not enabled by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think either of these things an be accomplished through the exp:channel:entries tag.  I'm sure you could accomplish both of these things through the [exp:query tag](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/query/index.html)

as an example of filtering based on a field I know contains only numbers:

```
{exp:query limit="5" sql="SELECT title, entry_date, field_id_5 
  FROM exp_channel_titles AS titles, exp_channel_data AS data 
  WHERE titles.entry_id = data.entry_id AND titles.entry_id > 900"}
    <p>{title} - {entry_date format="%Y %m %d"} - {field_id_5}</p>
{/exp:query}
```

On your second question, there is a date fieldtype, in ee but it doesn't allow for sorting based on that date in the channel:entries tag, just displaying the output formatted as a date.  To filter using the queries tag on dates, you need to be aware that the dates are stored as a unix timestamp.  If you wanted to query on your custom date field (here field_id_262) being between 14 and 7 days ago:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT titles.title, data.field_id_262 
  FROM exp_channel_titles AS titles, exp_channel_data AS data 
  WHERE titles.entry_id = data.entry_id 
  AND data.field_id_262 > ((unix_timestamp(Now()))-(14*86400)) 
  AND data.field_id_262 < ((unix_timestamp(Now()))-(7*86400))"}
    <p>{title} - {field_id_262 format="%Y %m %d"}</p>
{/exp:query}
```

Answer (score 8):

A quick addendum to the other answers (which are both fine for reading back values): **it is possible (and often a good idea) to change a text input field's allowed content from the default "all"** to "integer", "number", or "decimal". You can do this on the edit field screen:

[image]

This is important to do if you then want to filter/sort values numerically rather than alphanumerically, ie if you want the set `[32,3,133]` to be sorted as `[3,32,133]` and not as `[133,3,32]`. It's also important for ranges, as selecting `< 4` from the above range will select `[3,32,133]` if the field's content type is 'all' but `[3]` if the content type is 'integer'

Internally these values map to MySQL's `TEXT` ('all'), `INT` ('integer'), `NUMERIC` ('number') and `DECIMAL` ('decimal') datatypes.

When bypassing the `channel:entries` tag and pulling data direct from the DB, I tend to use the [**ActiveRecord plugin**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/activerecord) rather than the `query` tag as:

- It's far more secure if you're inserting dynamic data into your query, eg from url segments  (the `query` tag does not escape variables, whereas the AR plugin does).
- It syntax is much more readable, which helps you (or another developer) to work out what you  was trying to do when you return to the code months later
- There's no need to use prefixes (`exp_`) when selecting tables
- It supports pagination

Comment: That is great Tom, I forgot or didn't know that the content setting for input fields existed.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst a custom query is a good solution, you could also look to stash!

```
//This reads all your entries and records them as a list
{exp:stash:set_list name="my_entries" parse_tags="yes"}
{exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel"}

    {stash:entry_title}{title}{/stash:entry_title}
    {stash:entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:entry_id}
    {stash:theage}{my_age_field}{stash:theage}

{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list} 

//Using the list captured above, match an age (could be a segment as well) against
the age captured
{exp:stash:get_list name="my_entries" match=[#24#] against={theage} limit="10"}
    <p><a href="/my_template/{entry_id}">{title}</a></p>
    <p>This is item {count} of {total_results} rows curently being displayed.</p>
    <p>This is item {absolute_count} of {absolute_results} rows saved in this list</p>
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Just putting it out there :)

Comment: is your match and against right? match=[#24#] against={theage}